# Select the right matrix which satisfies a fair condition

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have set of `w` matrices in 3D.

```
w(:,:,1) =
    0.7791    0.0956    0.4664
    0.4257    0.4965    0.6954

w(:,:,2) =
    0.7791    0.1300    0.4749
    0.4257    0.7335    0.4552

w(:,:,3) =
    0.8823    0.7335    0.4664
    0.3944    0.1300    0.6954

w(:,:,4) =
    0.8823    0.4965    0.4749
    0.3944    0.0956    0.4552
```

I want to get minimum of each row of each matrix.

```
minEach=min(w,[],2);
minMat=reshape(minEach,[2 4])
```

It gives

```
minMat =    
    0.0956    0.1300    0.4664    0.4749
    0.4257    0.4257    0.1300    0.0956
```

Now I want to select the column with fairly higher values, which means each value in column should be fairly better than other columns. E.g., 4th column has the best value but its other value is bery low. So what I did, I get minimum of each column and select the maximum.

```
minAll=max(min(minMat)) 
minAll =    
    0.1300
```

Then, I have 2 options where I select maximum of other two values, where 3rd column is the best choice (I don't know how this step execute in Matlab). Then, I have to get the corresponding `w` matrix, which is `w(:,:,3)`.

**Question:** In general, `w` includes `n` no. of matrices each `w(:,:,i)` is `p x q` size. I am really confusing how I can select correct `w(:,:,i)` matrix which satisfies the fair condition. Specially, if `w(:,:,i)` is `5x6` and `minAll` value may be in 3 columns. Then, I have to repeat the same procedure again and again.

It would be great if someone could guide me.

Answer (score 0):

The next steps are:

find incides of columns that contain 0.13

extract those columns and concatenate them into a new matrix

In this matrix find indices of columns that contain maximum value

then obtain index of w `idx`

```
[~,c,~]=find(minMat == minAll);
minMat_selected= minMat(:,c);
[~,cc,~] = find(minMat_selected == max(minMat_selected(:)));
idx = c(cc(1));
w(:,:,idx)
```